# How do I tell my browser clients to clear their browser cache or force a hard reload?

Tags: javascript, browser

When I release a new version of my app I send a websocket event to my clients telling them that a new version is ready and they need to refresh their page to get the files.

I was hoping I could run something like this when receiving that websocket event:

```js
for (const cacheKey of await caches.keys()) {
  caches.delete(cacheKey)
}
```

However this only works if you have a serviceworker that is in charge of caching. I am using the simple cache-control header so this does not work for me.

My alternative strategy was to leave a flag in localstorage indicating that on the next load of the page, if the flag is there do a hard reload with:

```js
window.location.reload(true)
```

This would do a double reload, the second time removing the flag and getting the new files.

the force download argument is ignored by modern browsers though.

It seems I can't get my  clients to refresh without telling the users to manually erase their site settings (which is different on every device, iOS, Android, Chrome, Safari)

EDIT:

I looks like the only solution is to implement a service worker and manage my cache from there.

Any idea why `location.reload(true)` was deprecated? I know you can replicate it with a service worker with greater control - but SW feel like overkill for some use cases when a one liner is sufficient.

Comment: Why can't you use the good ol' `?v=1.2345`?